# Yeoman Install Saas Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yeoman, bower

I am creating a web app using yeoman and i want to include Bootstrap into the application.

When i run the following command

```
bower install --save bootstrap
```

It downloads Bootstrap in LESS format. Any way to download the SAAS based versions and install it into the project in Yeoman.

When i run

```
yo webapp
```

i dont get SAAS with Bootstrap but they come as different options.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you run "yo webapp" and leave marked, you will get Bootstrap in the SASS-version.
You will find the the "sass-bootstrap" files in "app/bower_components/sass-bootstrap"

What "yo webapp" does is actual equal to manuel include "sass-bootstrap" (https://github.com/jlong/sass-bootstrap) using bower

```
bower install --save sass-bootstrap
```

("yo webapp" ofcourse also installs modernizr, but that is not relevant for your question.)

Comment: when i run only yo webapp and use the option i get it via less.

Comment: So you don't get the folder "app/bower_components/sass-bootstrap" ? In that folder you should be able to find the SASS files in the lib-folder.

Comment: when i ran the command "bower install --save sass-bootstrap" i did. but when i edit the scss files there it doesnt do a live refresh i guess? have to switch on and off the grunt server

Comment: By default the grunt.js generated by "yo webapp" will only watch for SASS-files in "app/styles/". And livereload will only watch for css changes in "tmp/styles" (which is the output folder for sass precompile). If you want to have grunt watch the sass-bootstrap component, for sass changes, your will have to update the watch in grunt.js. The same goes if you want the livereload to watch for those changes.

Comment: But I would not recomend changing the files in the "app/bower_component/" folders, as those changes may be overriden by bower doing an update of the componemt. Instead create you own sass-file in "app/style/" and from that import the sass-files you want from the sass-bootstrap, and to an css-override of the things you want different.

Comment: @HarshaMV I had the same problem few minutes ago. Keep wondering why I can't get the SASS version. I kept getting the LESS. Then I figured that I need to use my spacebar to select the option Bootstrap and SASS before I hit enter to run the installation.